# Empty response from online WCF - long json string

Tags: javascript, jquery, wcf

I have this object which I submit in JSON format to a WCF

```
var j= {
                "Omschrijving": escape(encodeURI(document.getElementById('descr').value.trim())),
                "Foto" : "...", // VERY LONG STRING HERE (150 000 characters),
                "XCo": pLocation.x,
                "YCo": pLocation.y,
                "user": login,
                "Adres":escape(encodeURI(document.getElementById('map-location').innerHTML)),
                "Type": $('#meldingType').val()
            };
```

The foto attribute has been removed for the sake of this question. It counts about 150k characters.

This is the request to call the WCF from my phonegapp application:

```
 function corsRequest(j, url){
         response = "-9";   
            var xhr = createCORSRequest('POST', url);
            if (!xhr) {
                navigator.notification.alert("Gelieve een andere internetbrowser als standaard in te stellen.", null, "Fout");
                return;
            }
            // Response handlers.
            xhr.onload = function () {
                response = xhr.responseText;        
            };


            //xhr.send(JSON.stringify(j).replace(/"/g, '\''));
            var notJson = '"'+JSON.stringify(j).replace(/"/g, '\'')+'"';
            //alert(notJson);
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
            xhr.send(notJson);
```

and I have this as web.config

```
 <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="crossDomain" maxReceivedMessageSize="10485760">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"  maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="crossDomain" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" maxReceivedMessageSize="10485760">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"  maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>

  [...]

  <services>
        <service name="CeviService.CeviSpotter" behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceTypeBehaviors">
            <endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpBinding" address="mex"/>
    <endpoint address="ajaxEndpoint" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="CeviService.ICeviSpotter"  behaviorConfiguration="AjaxBehavior" bindingConfiguration="crossDomain">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
        </service>
    </services>
```

Here's the problem: when I submit a long JSON string (150k+ characters), it works perfectly on localhost. It gives me the value it should return on a succesful submit. However, when the webservice is put online, the response I get (which is alerted if the server connection is established or after 20 seconds (timeout)) is empty. This is weird, because the response is set to -9 in the beginning. If the response is still -9 after 20 seconds, there is a server timeout. If it is -1 (set by server), there is a server error (like syntax error or something). If it is 1, the command and function were executed succesfully. So the alert it shows is just empty. And the values aren't submitted to the database.

Now, am I doing something wrong, or is it because of the server settings? (it works on localhost, but not when I put it online)

Thanks in advance

EDIT: the WCF is surrounded by a try-catch, so there's no way there's an empty response

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that maxReceivedMessageSize property is set properly at the binding tag of both client and server web.config files.

Server web.config:

```
<bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding closeTimeout="04:01:00"
         openTimeout="04:01:00" receiveTimeout="04:10:00" sendTimeout="04:01:00"
         maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
         maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
         messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8">
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
         maxArrayLength="16348" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
        </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Client web.config:

```
<basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IMainService" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"/>
</basicHttpBinding>
```